# Send file to element in the database

Tags: php, database, select

I am working on a website with a database with many tables.

A table called "agency" includes a column for the names of the persons called (`E_NAME`) and other information in other columns.

There is another table called "tasks" for the tasks that the employee should perform.

How can I show the employees' names in a list and the responsible task presented in his account fter selecting the employee name?

This is the picture of the agency table:

[image: https://s26.postimg.org/4cr29vhqh/agency.png]

This is the picture of the tasks table:

[image: https://s26.postimg.org/n3szk1cax/recieved_tasks.png]

This is the PHP code for the selection:

```
<p>task for : 

<?php
 $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'taskproject');
                    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                        die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                    }



                     $query = "SELECT E_NAME FROM agency";

               $data = $dbLink->query($query);
                  //  $data = mysqli_query($dbLink,$query);             
?>


<select id="emp_name" name="mylist" onchange="selectedvalue(this.value)">
 <?php
     while($fetch_options = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { //Loop all the options retrieved from the query
     ?>


<option id ="<?php echo $fetch_options['ID']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $fetch_options['E_NAME']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_options['E_NAME']; ?></option><!--Echo  out options-->

<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any relationship between your agency and the tasks table. I think you need a field in your task table named something like `agency_id`. Then after selecting the employee name, you can search in your task table with your `employee_id`:

```
SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE agency_id = employee_id LIMIT 1
```